# How to retrieve array value index wise

Tags: mongodb

How do I retrieve an array value index-wise in MongoDB? In the below query, I want `Computers` as an answer:

```
> db.customers.find({}, { likes : { $slice: 1}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57709662a93160be074de74a"),
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : "40",
        "likes" : [
                "Computers"
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
db.customers.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,selected:{$slice:["$likes", 1]}}},{$unwind:"$selected"}]);
```